# Jquery click on popup div to show another div

Tags: javascript, jquery

The requirement is user can Click on black box to show orange box, and click on orange box to show red box, but the orange box and red box should be hidden
when user click anywhere of the document  except the orange box or the
red box itself.

But currently the issue is that we cannot click on orange box to show red box

Would much appreciate if you could help me out, thanks a lot

Demo link: http://plnkr.co/edit/OqlfbmFPKdXx0wDhnLxZ?p=preview

```js
$(function() {

  $('#mypop').click(function(e) {
    event.stopPropagation();
  });

  $(document).on('click', '#myclick', function() {
    $('#mypop').toggle();

    $(document).one('click', function() {
      $('#mypop').hide();
    });
  });

  $(document).on('click', '#myclick1', function() {
    $('#mypop2').show();
  });


  $(document).on('click', '#myclick2', function() {
    $('#mypop2').show();
  });

})()
```

```css
#mypop {
  background-color: orange;
  position: absolute;
  top: 130px;
  left: 50px;
  width: 150px;
  padding: 15px;
}

.mydiv {
  background-color: black;
  padding: 30px;
  width: 50px;
  cursor: pointer;
  color: white;
}

#mypop2 {
  margin-top: 150px;
  background-color: red;
  width: 100px;
  height: 50px;
  padding: 18px;
  display: none;
}

#myclick1,
#myclick2 {
  cursor: pointer;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="myclick" class='mydiv black-box'>
  click me!
</div>

<div id="mypop" style="display:none;" class='orange-box'>

  <p>hello world</p>
  <div id='myclick1'>BUTTON1</div>
  <div id='myclick2'>BUTTON2</div>
</div>

<div id="mypop2" class='red-box'>
  Hello World!!!
</div>
```

Comment: please read our [ask] page for hints on how to improve this question. (i.e. did you do a search for this before posting?) - also, include a [mcve] for faster troubleshooting.  btw, what exactly is the problem? you do not say what you are having issues with (we are not here to write code for you)

Comment: Looks like a homework

Comment: @ochi thanks, actually i put the demo link on my question as well. please kindly refer to this link, it's a demo. http://plnkr.co/edit/OqlfbmFPKdXx0wDhnLxZ?p=preview

Comment: Can you tell what problem exactly do you have?

Comment: @MaxZoom Problem is its not working as expected(those 4 points)

Comment: @Mils thanks a lot. it's not homework, it's an issue from my word, and i'm investigating how to fix it.

Comment: @MaxZoom thanks a lot for your comment. please refer to the demo in plunker, http://plnkr.co/edit/OqlfbmFPKdXx0wDhnLxZ?p=preview

Comment: @MaxZoom the issue  is that we cannot click on orange box to show red box

Comment: Please revert back your edit. Previous one was bit clear

Comment: In general, questions should be self-contained.  Putting a link with the code on an external site is OK as long as the code is also on the question.  If the link becomes unavailable for any reason, the question becomes impossible to answer without the code in it

Comment: @ochi thanks for your comment. really appreciate. I put the demo link along with this question now.

Comment: @ochi Demo link: http://plnkr.co/edit/OqlfbmFPKdXx0wDhnLxZ?p=preview

Comment: You should revert to your previous edit, where the code itself was in the question and didn't rely on an external resource like plnkr.

Comment: @Santi Thanks a lot, I'm a new comer and i will pay much attention next time

Comment: @ochi Thanks so much for helping edit this question, i will pay much attention.

Comment: @Jacob Can you please accept (and/or up-vote) any applicable answer?

Answer (score 1):

try this. I think this is what you are excepting but I'm not sure since you keep editing your question.

Demo Link: http://plnkr.co/edit/n7rdgqTwiFrXtpgoX4TQ?p=preview

```
   $('#myclick1').click(function(){
        $('#mypop2').show();
    });


    $('#myclick2').click(function(){
      $('#mypop2').show();
    });
```

Comment: Thanks so much, Anto, It's very close to my question. But when we click the anywhere of the document except the orange box and red box, the two boxes, orange and red should be hidden, currently only the orange hidden, the red one should be hidden as well. Thanks.

Comment: Really appreciate for your answer, I was inspired by you and now it's working and meet the requirements. Thanks a lot!!!

Answer (score 0):

You have couple of things mixed up.

**The main** stop-point was the very first event listener

```
$('#mypop').click(function(e) {
```

which is incompatible with the rest of listeners

```
$(document).on('click','#myclick1',function(e){
```

after I have changed it to

```
$(document).on('click','#mypop', function(e){
```

the other listeners have started working.

**Second** thing is that for embedded elements (parent-child) you need to stop event propagation, otherwise the parent event is triggered as well (which is not desired)

```
$(document).on('click','#myclick1',function(e){
  e.stopPropagation();
  :
});
```

I have also changed the CSS a bit and added class `hide` to use instead of styles. Toggling this class is what hides and shows an element.

Comment: thanks A lot. what's the difference betweenthose two event listener

Comment: Glad I could help. Please accept the answer if applicable.